# Graphql query using a variable for one of the arguments

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby and Graphql to build a website and I'm using the 'createPage' API from Gatsby to create all my pages, sourcing the data from the graphql CMS https://hygraph.com/.

I can pass over dynamic values to my template just fine using the 'gatsby-node.js' file and createPage's 'context' like so:

```
createPage({
  path: `/path-to-my-page',
  component: require.resolve(`./src/my-template.js`),
  context: {
    product_attribute: "metal",
    product_attributeValue: "silver"
  },
})
```

When I come to create the page query in my template, I have passed over one dynamic value to my template, the "product_attributeValue" and the following code works just fine:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ProductListingByAttributeQuery(
    $product_attribute: String
    $product_attributeValue: String
  ) {
    gcms {
      products(
        orderBy: updatedAt_DESC
        where: {
          metal: $product_attributeValue
        }
      ) {
        slug
        title
        image
        content
      }
    }
  }
`
```

But what I really want to do is use the "product_attribute" variable in the "where" instead of the string 'metal' like so:

```
where: {
    $product_attribute: $product_attributeValue
}
```

But I get syntax errors saying it doesn't like that I've used `$product_attribute` in the `where: {...}` object.  The error says "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $".

Is it possible to do what I want to do here? In that I want to use the variable 'product_attribute' instead of a string?

Comment: Not an expert on the JS GraphQL API but I bet you can do something like `where: ${someVar}: $product_attributeValue`, but it would have to be a variable from the JS, not the GraphQL

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work, I got an error saying that "String interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use "standard" GraphQL syntax in Gatsby's umbrella, since Gatsby ships its own GraphQL implementation where [`where` filter is not a valid operator](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/). If you test the query in the GraphiQL playground, it will break (output the same error message) since it's not a valid option.

You are passing the context values properly but using them in an invalid way, you may want to use `filter`, along with `in`, `ni`, `nin` operators. More references: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/

For example:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query ProductListingByAttributeQuery(
    $product_attribute: String
    $product_attributeValue: String
  ) {
    gcms(productType: {eq: $product_type}) {
      products {
        slug
        title
        image
        content
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Note: this is not intended to be a copy/paste. It needs to be tweaked and refined*

Something like this should work but as I said, test it and built the query using the GraphiQL playground (at `localhost:8000/___graphql`), it's really helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about using filter and I took a look at the link, but couldn't get some of the examples working in the GraphiQL playground.  The examples in that link didn't show a complete query and I didn't know how to bring their examples in to my code.

I've edited my original question and removed some of the code noise, but I don't need to filter by "productType" like you gave in your example, I need to filter by the two variables "product_attribute" and "product_attributeValue" together.

Thanks for your help so far

Comment: You should be able to achieve it given the available filters. Another option is using JS to filter the data, the passed contexts are available inside `props.pageContext`